# adjusting lists so that drawing elements from them leads to a uniform distribution

Tags: r, random, normal-distribution, probability-density, uniform-distribution

I have 2 lists, and I would like to sample elements from each of the lists and then calculate the difference between them (get the nth index from list A and nth index from list B and subtract them). When I plot the probability density of the difference, I see that the result is normally distributed, which is expected (see the example and plot below).

Is there a way to adjust the lists so that randomly drawing elements from each, when subtracted by the same nth index, would lead to similar frequencies of occurrences across the range of possibilities? In other words, can I arrange the list so that the subtraction of randomly drawn elements from each list leads to uniform distribution?

I provided the code below to illustrate my question.

```
listA <- -10:10
listB <- -10:10

#plot the distribution of the list
hist(listB, freq = FALSE, xlab = 'x', density = 20)

#sample random elements from both of the lists
sampledListA <- sample(listA, 1000, replace = TRUE)
sampledListB <- sample(listB, 1000, replace = TRUE) 

# I then draw one element from each of the lists and I calculate the difference of the two drawn value
# and I want the occurrences of the differences to be similar in probability.

# I can calculate the difference by element
listDiff <- sampledListA - sampledListB

#here is the normal distribution this leads to
hist(listDiff, freq = FALSE, xlab = 'x', density = 20)
```

[image: difference distribution]

```
# I can calculate the possible differences using the outer function

diffMatrix <- data.frame(outer(listA,listB, '-'))

#change the column and row names
library(stats)
nms <- as.character(listA)
rownames(diffMatrix) <- nms
names(diffMatrix) <- nms
diffMatrix

# I can then find the list of possible unique differences, and draw samples from that
vectorized <- unlist(diffMatrix)
diffRange <- unique(vectorized)

getDiffSamples<-sample(diffRange, 1000, replace = TRUE) #get 1000 random sample from each diff value
hist(getDiffSamples,freq = FALSE, xlab = 'x', density = 20) #then I will have uniform distribution

# I can then get any value from this distribution, find its index (location of row and column) in the matrix of differences
which(diffMatrix == a[1], arr.ind=TRUE)

# but I am looking for a way to adjust the list, because, my ultimate goal is to have a list of A and B that when I randomly pick one from each list and 
# get the subtraction of the pair when plotted U(listA, listB) will have the shape of uniform probability.
```